# How to use Mutiple between Caluse in Where Condition in SQL SERVER

Tags: asp.net, sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, unique

I want to get data of different ranges like "`SUBSCRIBER_ZIP between '30000' and '31999'`"
and "`SUBSCRIBER_ZIP between '39813' and '39901'`" and "`SUBSCRIBER_ZIP between '32000' and '34999'`".

I want to get all the Active records(means status=1) having this search criteria. I have used Union for this but it does not provide me unique records:

```
Select distinct(SUBSCRIBER_EMAIL), SUBSCRIBER_Id FROM
 (select distinct(SUBSCRIBER_EMAIL),SUBSCRIBER_ID from SUBSCRIBER where SUBSCRIBER_ACTIVE = 1  and SUBSCRIBER_ZIP between '30000' and '31999'    
  Union    
 select distinct(SUBSCRIBER_EMAIL),SUBSCRIBER_ID from SUBSCRIBER where SUBSCRIBER_ACTIVE = 1  and SUBSCRIBER_ZIP between '39813' and '39901'    
  Union 
 select distinct(SUBSCRIBER_EMAIL),SUBSCRIBER_ID from SUBSCRIBER where SUBSCRIBER_ACTIVE = 1  and SUBSCRIBER_ZIP between '32000' and '34999'    
 ) x
```

But it does not provide me unique results. Please help me how can i do it.

Comment: What are the duplicate values you are getting? And is SUBSCRIBER_ZIP some kind of text field rather than a numeric field? If so it will be using text ordering which means that `"33"` will come between `"32000"` and `"34999"`. Though if they are always five characters you'll get away with this I think.

Comment: is Subscriber_ZIP a text field ?

Comment: yes.. @SirajMansour that's not a big problem problem is how to get distinct records..

Comment: raman: you got duplicate records because something is satisfying more than one of your zip checks. I can't think how this is happening offhand whcih is why I asked for an example of one of the duplicates to try to understand better.

Comment: This is an XY problem: it's no use fixing the query because the problem is in the table (or view) `SUBSCRIBER`. Please supply sample data. http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem

Comment: what you want to say?

Comment: Even if you have record satistying more than one of zip checks, the values should not be duplicated in the Ruud solution since the query contains the distinct. I cant see how values could be duplicated. Have you tried to filter one of duplicated records in where clause just to understand the problem better?

Comment: Are you sure that some space at the end of one of the fields it is not the problem. They are almost invisible but make difference when you are trying to distinguish them visually.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use `OR`?

```
select distinct SUBSCRIBER_EMAIL, SUBSCRIBER_ID
from SUBSCRIBER
where SUBSCRIBER_ACTIVE = 1
and (
    SUBSCRIBER_ZIP between '30000' and '31999' or
    SUBSCRIBER_ZIP between '39813' and '39901' or
    SUBSCRIBER_ZIP between '32000' and '34999'
)
```

Comment: Then either your table contains duplicates, or `SUBSCRIBER` is a view rather than a table. Either way, the query is not to blame.

Comment: Though the more I look at this I realise that with the distinct at the beginning it should be impossible for there to be duplicates in the result set...

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT DISTINCT [SUBSCRIBER_EMAIL],[SUBSCRIBER_ID] FROM SUBSCRIBER WHERE ([SUBSCRIBER_ACTIVE] = 1) AND 
(
  (CAST(SUBSCRIBER_ZIP AS INT) BETWEEN 30000 AND 31999) 
OR
  (CAST(SUBSCRIBER_ZIP AS INT) BETWEEN 39813 AND 39901)
OR
  (CAST(SUBSCRIBER_ZIP AS INT) BETWEEN 32000 AND 34999)
)
```

Note : Don't use quotations for the numbers